# Differentiation on $\mathbb{R}^2$ for row vectors:

Tags: notation, vectors

Let  $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be a differntiable function defined for  every  $x=(x_1,x_2)$ by  $$f(x)= (f_1(x),f_2(x),f_3(x))$$ 
Let $Df$ denote its differentiation. Then $Df(x)$ is a linear map from  $ \mathbb{R}^2 $ into $\mathbb{R}^3 $.

I would like to define $Df(x)$ while keeping the row vector notation of  $\mathbb{R}^2 $, so how can I do this?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think that I'm not understanding your question, but the transpose of the Jacobian should be what you're talking about.

Comment: To clarify what I mean,  the Jacobian matrix has dimensions : $ 3 \times  2 $, so its transpose has dimension  $ 2 \times 3$. this cannot be defined with row vector since multiplication is not compatible:  $2 \times 3$ and  $1 \times  2$.

Comment: @nizar You have to multiply on the right by the transponse of the usual matrix.

Comment: You are not quite defining derivatives: you are just using a different notation for coordinate vector spaces, and thus a different action of $\Bbb R^{m\times n}$ over them to indicate the linear maps.

Comment: You must multiply the $1\times 2$ row vector by the transpose of the Jacobian $2\times 3$.  So, vector*Jacobian.